# Git remotes with slashes break automatic tracking during checkout?

Tags: git

I have this:

```
$ git branch -r
github/foo/a-branch
```

Typically, this works:

```
$ git checkout a-branch
error: pathspec 'a-branch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Of course, `a-branch` doesn't exist; typically, git will create a new tracking branch tracking the one in the remote. That said, *if I rename the remote*:

```
$ git remote rename github/foo github-foo
$ git checkout a-branch
Branch a-branch set up to track remote branch a-branch from github-foo.
Switched to a new branch 'a-branch'
```

Why should the name of the remote ever effect whether `git` will set up a tracking branch for me?

Comment: Sounds like it's probably a bug--somewhere it's assuming that remotes won't have slashes in them, and that's not good for your case.  You should report this to the git mailing list.  See the [Git Community](http://git-scm.com/community) for more details about the list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try explicitly specifying the full pathspec of the remote branch you wish to track?

```
git checkout -b a-branch --track github/foo/a-branch
```

Also, concerning setup of tracked branches, referencing from http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> `$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>`

Git also has a `branch.autosetupmerge` configuration setting which automatically sets up tracking from the remote you pulled from.